# How to get rid of of page parameter in url

Tags: php, yii, pagination, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm creating pretty pagination rules on my site using [Pagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html#$forcePageParam-detail) and url configs specified [here](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/pagination-pretty-urls/) . Everything works fine, but I'm getting duplicate content according to Google.

```
http://example.com/tag/movie/2
```

and

```
http://example.com/tag/movie?page=2
```

These are two valid urls, contains same content. And my question is how to remove `?page=2` parameter.

Here is my urlManager configs

```
'rules' => [
'/' => 'site/index',
'tag/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>/<page:\d+>' => 'site/tag-view',
'tag/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>' => 'site/tag-view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/action>',
'<url:.+>/' => 'site/redirect',],
```

And Pagination settings:

```
 $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery->count(),'defaultPageSize' => 5,  'forcePageParam' => false, ]);
```

Comment: Generated an invalid link or do you want the second URL not to be accessible?

Comment: I want the second URL not to be accessible

Comment: I think it's better to do this by setting up your web server.
Because for the Yii2, these URLs are almost the same.

Comment: You can use canonical url so that google doesn't mark urls as duplicate content.